# R script to process all data files in a folder did not work

Tags: r

I wrote a R code to process files in a folder and I need some help on using the file name for its name of data frame.

There is no error messages when I run the following R code. I want each looping to create its data frame; the name of its data frame is named by its file name.

Please help me to get it work.

Here is my R code:

```
    files <- list.files(path="/Users/me/Desktop/mydatefolder20151217", pattern=".TXT")

for (fname in files) {
    fname <- read.table(fname)
    if (ncol(fname) == 11) {  
       fname<-subset(fname, select=-c(V7))
    }
    colnames(fname) <- c("ID","yy","mm","dd","HH","MM","Temp","Rh","Vs","Vf")       
    fname$Temp[fname$Temp < -50 | fname$Temp > 50] <- NA
    fname$DateTime <- as.POSIXct(paste(fname$yy, fname$mm, fname$dd, fname$HH, fname$MM), format = "%y %m %d %H %M")   
}
```

Comment: Your for loop is writing over itself. Create an empty list to hold the data frames first, then assign each iteration to it.

Comment: Can you explain more? I just add fname <- data.frame() in the outside the loop. It did not work.

Comment: I added a possible solution. If you add some actual data, I can test to ensure that it works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can clean up the code by saving the data frame transformations to a list that can accessed after. I cannot test this to see if it works; you did not provide any actual data in your example. :

```
files <- list.files(path="/Users/me/Desktop/mydatefolder20151217", pattern=".TXT")

all_dfs <- vector("list", length(files))

for (i in 1:length(files)) {
  df <- read.table(files[i])
  if (ncol(df) == 11) {  
    df <- subset(df, select=-c(V7))
  }
  colnames(df) <- c("ID","yy","mm","dd","HH","MM","Temp","Rh","Vs","Vf")       
  df$Temp[df$Temp < -50 | df$Temp > 50] <- NA
  df$DateTime <- with(df, as.POSIXct(paste(yy, mm, dd, HH, MM), format = "%y %m %d %H %M"))

  all_dfs[[i]] <- df

  names(all_dfs)[i] <- paste0("df", i)                    
}
```

Comment: It now stores all dataset to a large list named all_dfs. Is it possible to separate them to each individual data frame?? Thanks a lot for your guidance.

Comment: There's no need to do that. You can access them all in the form `all_dfs[[1]]`. But if you really need them out use `list2env(all_dfs)`.

Comment: Check the answer again. I added an extra line to get easy names like `df1` and `df2` at the end.

Answer (score 0):

Add `full.names=TRUE` to your `list.files` call.

Also, note that `pattern` should be a *regular expression*, not a shell wildcard expression. If you want all files with extension `.txt`, use `pattern="\\.TXT$"`. And since it looks like you're on Windows, add `ignore.case=TRUE` for good measure.

Comment: Not working. It just shows one data frame named "fname".

Comment: @Kuo-HsienChang I haven't looked at your for loop. This answer should ensure that your `files` vector actually contains the full pathnames that you want.

Comment: I am using a Mac. The file names were used the extension .TXT  I guess I did not do the loop correctly. It seems just shows the last loop.